# Spring properties file path reference?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring. I have placed properties file in `src/main/resources` and trying to refer it in a spring `bean` as below.

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("classpath:AwsCredentials.properties");

AWSCredentials credentials = new PropertiesCredentials(input);
```

Above code did not work and it says `File not found`. Is there any wrong? Please help me.

Comment: After compiling is that properties file still in your classpath?

Comment: I dont know and it has been placed in src/main/resources folder in my project.

Comment: Check at the location where all your compiled classes are located.

Comment: it has been kept under WEB-INF\classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Springs [resource loading](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html) mechanism to get the `InputStream` to a given `Resource`.

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("path/to/AwsCredentials.properties");
AWSCredentials credentials = new PropertiesCredentials(resource.getInputStream());
```

However instead of managing those things yourself I would strongly suggest using the [`Environment` abstraction](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-environment) and construct a `BasicCredentials`. That saves you handling the resource and getting the input stream. And you could possible have multiple ways of configuring that AWS credentials.

```
@PropertySource("classpath:AwsCredentials.properties")
public class AWSConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public AwsCredentials credentials() {
        String secretKey = env.getRequiredProperty("name of property");
        String accessKey = env.getRequiredProperty("name of property");
        return new BasicCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
    }

}
```

Now Spring is taking care of loading the resource for you.

**Note:** Both samples assume that the `AwsCredentials.properties` is in the root of the classpath. If it is in a sub directory/package you need to add that.

Answer (score 0):

I use getClass().getResource() approach to read files placed in /resources folder

This example reads json, but should work for property files as well.

```
String json = null;

    try {
        URI path = getClass().getResource("/" + file).toURI();
        json = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)));
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        logger.error("error in path to the file", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("error while reading the file", e);
    }
    return json;
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this for your correction:-

```
Resource resource = 
           appContext.getResource("classpath:src/main/resources/AwsCredentials.properties");
try{
          InputStream is = resource.getInputStream();
          AWSCredentials credentials = new PropertiesCredentials(input);
}catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: That won't work. `src/main/resources` is the root of the class path. So just `classpath:AwsCredentials.properties` is enough.

Comment: it did not work. Caught Exception: classpath:AwsCredentials.properties (The system cannot find th
e file specified)